# Django rest-framework ListCreateAPIView doesn't return the full path for the file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I just started using Django rest-framework, and I wanted the JSON response to return the URL for the file stored in the server, I used `generics.ListCreateAPIView` class

```py
class PeopleList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = People.objects.all().order_by('registration_time')
    serializer_class = PeopleSerializer
```

and it worked actually! it returned a full path clickable URL:

```json
{
        "id": 1,
        ...
        "profile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/profile_image/IMG_20190826_105834_vwKLf10.jpg",
        ...
    },
```

But then I had to use the list function because  I needed the request object.

```py
class PeopleList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = People.objects.all().order_by('registration_time')
    serializer_class = PeopleSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            queryset = People.objects.all().order_by('registration_time')
            serializer_class = PeopleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            print(serializer_class.data)
            return Response(serializer_class.data)
        else:
            content = {'Authentication Error': 'Please Login!'}
            return Response(content, status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

Now the response only contains the path without  the domain:

```json
  {
        "id": 1,
        ...
        "profile": "/media/profile_image/IMG_20190826_105834_vwKLf10.jpg",
        ...
    },
```

so the question is, How can I return the whole URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `request` to the context passed to your serializer:

```
serializer_class = PeopleSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request':request})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Adel's answer. If you ever need to access the absolute URI, then `request.build_absolute_uri()` should suffice.